# How to make $childrenWrapClass true

Tags: navigation

im trying to get a div to wrap the second level nav items in my navigation and have found out about the $childrenWrapClass attribute of renderCategoryMenuItemHtml call in the top.phtml file

What is the correct way of setting this to true so my children nav gets wrapped in the div?

thanks

**EDIT**
I have implemented the answer below but seem to have an error in this part of the process:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="catalog.topnav">
        <action><template>cranbri/vertnavflyout/page/html/topmenu.phtml</template></ac‌​tion>
    </reference>
</default>
```

I have an error on the action tags saying "tag has wrong closing name" any ideas?

Also i have a 3 tier menu, will this wrap  ONLY the 2nd tier or both the second and third? If it wraps both is there any way i can add a unique identifier to the class? say like a 1 for the 2nd tier and a 2 on the third tier?

Thanks

Comment: $childrenWrapClass is wrap css class name it is not Boolean value. So you should rewrite template for that. Follow the instructions in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create rewrite module:

MyNamespace - could be your company name or project name.

MymoduleName - for example could be ExtendMenu.

### Defining the module

In `app/etc/modules` create module initialization file `MyNamespace_MymoduleName.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNamespace_MymoduleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyNamespace_MymoduleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

### Creating the module subfolders

Create the following folder-structure within the app/code/local directory:

- MyNamespace
- MyNamespace/MymoduleName
- MyNamespace/MymoduleName/etc

### The XML configuration

Create a configuration-file MyNamespace/MymoduleName/etc/config.xml which contains XML-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNamespace_MymoduleName>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyNamespace_MymoduleName>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mynamespace_mymodulename>
                    <file>mynamespace/mymodulename.xml</file>
                </mynamespace_mymodulename>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

### The XML layout

In `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/` create folder `mynamespace` and file `mymodulename.xml` in it.

The config.xml now points towards an mymodulename.xml file, which is located `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mynamespace`.

Now add some content to mymodulename.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="catalog.topnav">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>mynamespace/mymodulename/page/html/topmenu.phtml</template>
            </ac‌​tion>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

### Rewriting template

In `app\design\frontend\base\default\template` folder create `\mynamespace\mymodulename\page\html\topmenu.phtml`. Copy html code from `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml` and set `'your_css_wrapper_class'` as second param for `function getHtml`.

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top', 'your_css_wrapper_class') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
       <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Clear all cache.

See your menu html code. Second level elements should be wrapped in:

```
<div class="your_css_wrapper_class"></div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, i seem to have a problem with part of the code. in the code for the xml layout you have shown above, i am getting errors on the action tags saying "wrong closing tag name", why would i be receiving this error? i think this is stopping it from working, thanks

Comment: Maybe something with encoding because you made spy/past. Just delete that tag and type it by your own. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Thankyou for your help it is now working and i now understand magento a bit more!. As per my question above what is the best way to make the class name different for each tier it descends? thanks

Comment: I am sorry but why do you do you need that?

Comment: I want to use the div to surround the sub menu in order to place it absolutely next to my vertical navigation and display the sub-sub menu items under the sub menu titles if this makes sense? and because the sub-submenu is getting the div wrap as well anything i do to #nav .column effects both the sub menu and sub-submenu when i only want it to effect the submenu. Thanks

Comment: But why do you need different class name for every sub menu item?

Comment: How would you suggest i edit the style of the first class and not the nested class if it has the same class name? Thanks

Comment: `.nav > .class_name:first-child`

Comment: Ok ill give it a go. thank you so much for your help and patience, i appreciate it so much