# How can I add category IDs as a class on the top menu?

Tags: menu, core

I'm trying to add classes such as `cat-1`, `cat-2`, ...,  `cat-n` to the `<li>` elements in the top menu, *where the number is the category ID*. I would also like to add `cat-0` to the "Home" link.

At first I thought this would be fairly simple - just edit a theme phtml file or something, then I dug a little deeper and found `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php` which seems to be where the action is.

This seems like I file I shouldn't be messing with, and all of a sudden, I'm way out of my depth.

**So what's the best way to add category ID-based class names to `<li>` tags in the top menu?** Some kind of module that overrides a function in the aforementioned file?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution will be override some method of `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php`.

A small tutorial how to write override extension you can find  [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13894/how-to-make-childrenwrapclass-true/13897) in my answer. The only difference that you do not need override template, you need override model.

Comment: If this answer helped you. You can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');  $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();  $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category')  if (count($_categories) > 0): foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
<li class="haschild">
    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
        <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
    </a>
    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
        <ul class="">
            <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                        <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php $_categorysub = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_subcategoriessub = $_categorysub->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategoriessub) > 0): ?>

                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <?php foreach($_subcategoriessub as $_subcategorysub): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategorysub) ?>">
                            <?php echo $_subcategorysub->getName() ?>
                            </a>
                            <?php $_categorysubtosub = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategorysub->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_categorysubtosub = $_categorysubtosub->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                         <?php if (count($_categorysubtosub) > 0): ?>
                            <ul class="submenu1 <?php echo 'p'.$_subcategorysub->getId() ?>">
                                <?php foreach($_categorysubtosub as $_categorysubtosub): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_categorysubtosub) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_categorysubtosub->getName() ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```